# Python complexity of slice combined with asterisk for tuples

Tags: python-3.x

what is the complexity of the following example:

```
tuple_ = (1,2,..,3,1) # tuple of length n
(*tuple_[:k], *tuple_[k+1:]) # deleting element at index k
```

Normally the slicing is `O(k)` and `O(n-k)` for `tuple_[:k]` and `tuple_[k+1:]` respectively.
but does the slicing first occur and then the elements are added one by one to the resulting tuple meaning another `n` operations?
I know that the complexity is O(2n) is just O(n) but I would like to know if the number of operations is doubled here because of the asterisk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have an input:

```
tuple_ = tuple(range(1000))
k = 400
```

Let's analyze 2 expressions: `(tuple_[:k], tuple_[k+1:])` and `(*tuple_[:k], *tuple_[k+1:])` using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#module-dis) module to discover and compare what significant operations are performed *under the hood*.

***Expression #1***:

```
import dis

...
dis.dis("(tuple_[:k], tuple_[k+1:])")
```

---

```
 1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (tuple_)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 LOAD_NAME                1 (k)
              6 BUILD_SLICE              2
              8 BINARY_SUBSCR
             10 LOAD_NAME                0 (tuple_)
             12 LOAD_NAME                1 (k)
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             16 BINARY_ADD
             18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 BUILD_SLICE              2
             22 BINARY_SUBSCR
             24 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

The significant operations here are `BUILD_SLICE` 1, `BUILD_SLICE` 2 and `BUILD_TUPLE` which gather up the running time of the expression to **`O(k)` + `O(n - (k + 1))` + `O(2)`**(as the final tuple `BUILD_TUPLE` contains only 2 slices/tuples).

---

***Expression #2***:

`dis.dis("(*tuple_[:k], *tuple_[k+1:])")`

---

```
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (tuple_)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 LOAD_NAME                1 (k)
              8 BUILD_SLICE              2
             10 BINARY_SUBSCR
             12 LIST_EXTEND              1
             14 LOAD_NAME                0 (tuple_)
             16 LOAD_NAME                1 (k)
             18 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             20 BINARY_ADD
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 BUILD_SLICE              2
             26 BINARY_SUBSCR
             28 LIST_EXTEND              1
             30 LIST_TO_TUPLE
             32 RETURN_VALUE
```

Here Python builds an empty list from the start with `BUILD_LIST`. Several reasons for that: 1) the unpacking requires **flattening** a sequence; 2) not all arguments might need to be unpacked, so the flattening can be arranged on different points on the final container. Knowing that `tuple` is immutable, the `list` is used as internal storage.

The significant operations here are `BUILD_SLICE` 1, `LIST_EXTEND` 1, `BUILD_SLICE` 2, `LIST_EXTEND` 2 and `LIST_TO_TUPLE`. Those gather the running time of the expression to **`O(2k)` + `O(2(n - (k + 1)))` + `O(n)`**

The complexity seems quite representative.

Comment: Might also be worth comparing against `tuple_[:k] + tuple_[k+1:]`